# How to increase numbers without joining them in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, runtime-error

I'm working on a script in Python but I have a problem:
The for loop is supposed to run code in the loop until it reaches the variable 'leng'. Because for loops stop at right before the stop value is reached, I need the stop value to be 1 more than leng. I have a script that looks something like this:

```
leng = input()
for i in range(1, (leng + 1)):
```

but I always get the error message in the shell:

```
t_Creator_v1.py", line 9, in <module>
for i in range (1, (leng + 1)):
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly
```

I tried searching stackoverflow but I couldn't find any results that suit me. How would I get what result I want? Please respond, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your taking in just normal `input` from the user which returns as a `string` representation of the data they enter. You need to parse it into an `int` if you want to do what you're trying.

```
leng = int(input())
for i in range(1, (leng + 1)):
```